# For loop with keys of property list

Tags: loops, property-list

I am using a properties list and I would like to be able to create a command that produces the list of keys to be used to generate a for loop. I am currently using \prop_map_inline to generate all the keys but if I use this in the for loop it is interpreted as a single item and not a collection of several items.

This is an example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \prop_new:N \g_persons_prop
    
    % Create a new person
    \NewDocumentCommand{\CreatePerson}{m} {
        \prop_gput:Nnn \g_persons_prop { #1 }
    }
    
    % Gets all persons
    \NewDocumentCommand{\GetAllPersonKeys}{}{
        \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_persons_prop {
            ##1, 
        }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\CreatePerson{jd}{John Doe}
\CreatePerson{ad}{Albert Dull}
\CreatePerson{bu}{Ben Under}

\begin{document}
    I would like to have this:
    \makeatletter
        \begin{itemize}
            \@for\sun:={jd, ad, bu}\do{\item We have person: \sun. }
        \end{itemize}
     \makeatother
    
    But I get this instead:
    
    \makeatletter
        \begin{itemize}
            \@for\sun:={\GetAllPersonKeys}\do{\item We have person: \sun. }
        \end{itemize}
     \makeatother   

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: How many arguments do you intend `CreatePerson` to take?

Comment: What do you really want to do? Why not just `prop_map_inline ... {We have person: ...}`?

Comment: If you want some keywords to learn yourself, there are 2 issues here • `GetAllPersonKeys` as implemented as not expandable, and • you didn't even try to expand it before executing `@for`, so no guarantee.

Comment: I want to be able to use \@for over the keys, in this case jd, ad, bu. I want this because I want to be able to do general loops in which I use the keys. I want to avoid having \ExplSyntaxOn on the main code (I am working on a class). The points you mention in your third comment are my issue. I do not know how to expand it such that it can be used. I tried googling but I could not find an answer I could extrapolate to this case.

Comment: TeX programming is hard, if you don't learn it properly you'll get full of surprises. I guess if you want you can start at [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Back to this point, it looks like that `\@for` f-expand the argument. So you have to use something f-expandable, such as `\use:e`'s `\expanded` emulation plus some other `prop_map` function that is hollow-star. Try it yourself, if `\tl_show:f {\GetAllPersonKeys}` shows the correct comma-separated result you know it's correct.

Comment: Alternatively if you allow some interface change, change the interface to `\GetAllPersonKeys \@for \sun :={\AllPersonKeysResult} \do {...}` it would be much easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I do not understand you last comment. What are you proposing? Something like \edef\AllPersonKeysResult{\GetAllPersonKeys}? I tried it and it also does not work. Coul you explain it more?

Comment: \GetAllPersonsKeys is not expandable so you can't use it there. You could define it so that it fills a suitable command, but on the whole you are only making your live difficult by missing expl3 with \@for like this. Stick to one system.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer! Then what would be the alternative without using expl3? I mean, how can I replace the property lists?

Comment: Well expl3 is implemented using just TeX after all, so if you are good enough at TeX you can reimplement everything you want. I don't recommend it though

Comment: I said that, there **exists** an implementation such that `\GetAllPersonKeys \@for \sun :={\AllPersonKeysResult} \do {...}` does what you want, but you **need** the initial `\GetAllPersonKeys` to be **outside**. If you're happy with that the answer would be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map over the keys in expl3 too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
    \prop_new:N \g_persons_prop

    % Create a new person
    \NewDocumentCommand{\CreatePerson}{m} {
        \prop_gput:Nnn \g_persons_prop { #1 }
    }

    \NewDocumentCommand{\MapAllPersonKeys}{m}{
        \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_persons_prop {
           #1
        }
    }
    
    
\ExplSyntaxOff

\CreatePerson{jd}{John Doe}
\CreatePerson{ad}{Albert Dull}
\CreatePerson{bu}{Ben Under}

\begin{document}
    I would like to have this:
    
      \makeatletter
        \begin{itemize}
            \@for\sun:={jd, ad, bu}\do{\item We have person: \sun. }
        \end{itemize}
     \makeatother
     
      \begin{itemize}
           \MapAllPersonKeys{\item we have person: #1!}
      \end{itemize}
    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is quite magical. Do I understand correctly that it replaces #1 in the command definition by #1 when calling as you propose?